# Groovy hasProperty/respondsTo

Tags: groovy

All the [examples](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/10/groovy-goodness-check-if-method-or.html) I see of using `hasProperty` or `respondsTo` show it being invoked on a `metaClass`. Is there a reason why these methods shouldn't be invoked on the object itself, like this:

```
def propertyName = 'time'

if (new Date().hasProperty(propertyName))
  println 'yes'
else 
  println 'no'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is discussed in this [thread](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/class-hasProperty-or-class-metaClass-hasProperty-td370195.html).  Looks like they refer to the same thing in current versions of Groovy, but this was not always the case, as only the `metaClass` had that call.