# faunus script map completing but not mutating graph

Tags: gremlin, titan, faunus

Prelude:  Several months experience using both Gremlin "dialects" for FaunusGraph & TitanGraph, so well aware of the functional and syntactic diffs.  Have successfully used Faunus script step (http://architects.dzone.com/articles/distributed-graph-computing , https://github.com/thinkaurelius/faunus/blob/master/src/main/java/com/thinkaurelius/faunus/mapreduce/sideeffect/ScriptMap.java) for relatively simple deletion & mutation of subgraphs.

Problem:  Implemented a complex mutation script map to "move" edge properties to either the out-vertex or the in-vertex per a direction-oriented convention for naming properties.  My TitanGraph Gremlin prototype works on small graphs, but I can't get the scaled-up implementation to work: the map completes successfully but the graph isn't changed (I am committing the changes).  NOTE: my Logger object is only outputing the first INFO message that displays the prefix args, indicating I'm not satifying the edge namespace guard condition (I did a run without the condition, but no change).   Following is my code (fat-fingering from an internal net, so typos are possible)

```
//faunus pipe driver - usage gremlin -e faunus.ns.set-props.grm
import java.io.Console

//get args
console=System.console()
arg=console.readLine('> type <namespace>;<faunus.ns.set-props.mapper_path>;<from_prefix>;<to_prefix>
inargs=arg.split(";")

//establish FaunusGraph connection
f=FaunusFactory.open('titan-client.properties')
f.getConf().set("faunus.graph.input.titan.storage.read-consistency-level", "ALL")
f.getConf().set("faunus.graph.input.titan.storage.write-consistency-level", "ALL")

//Faunus pipe incl. script step
f.V().has("_namespace", inargs[0]).script(inargs[1], inargs[2], inargs[3]

//script map - usage f.V().has("_namespace", <namespace_string>).script(<this_script_path>, <outV_key_prefix_string>, <inV_key_prefix_string>)

def g
def mylog

def setup(args) {
    mylog=java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("script_map")
    println("configuring graph ...")
    conf=new BaseConfiguration()
    conf.setProperty("storage.backend", "cassandra")
    conf.setProperty("storage.keyspace", "titan")
    conf.setProperty("storage.index.index-name", "titan")
    conf.setProperty("storage.hostname", "localhost")
    g=TitanFactory.open(conf)
}

def map(v, args) {
    mylog.info("*****READ***** args: "+args[0].toString()+", "+args[1].toString())

    //fetch all edges incident on Titan vertex corresponding to incoming Faunus vertex
    gv=g.v(v.id)
    edges=gv.bothE();null

    //iterate through incident edges
    while(edges.hasNext()) {
        e=edges.next()
        if (e.hasProperty("_namespace")) { //_namespace removed from previously processed edges
            /*fetch terminal vertices of current edge, add incidence & adjacency props
            to support metrics and analytics
            */
            from=e.getVertex(OUT)
            from.setProperty("inV_degree", from.in().count())
            from.setProperty("inE_degree", from.inE().count())
            from.setProperty("outV_degree" from.out().count())
            from.setProperty("outE_degree", from.outE().count())

            to=e.getVertex(IN)
            to.setProperty("inV_degree", from.in().count())
            to.setProperty("inE_degree", from.inE().count())
            to.setProperty("outV_degree" from.out().count())
            to.setProperty("outE_degree", from.outE().count())

            mylog.info("*****READ*****edge id:  "+e.id)
            mylog.info("*****READ*****edge vertices:  from id"+fromid+"; to id:  "+to.id)

            //fetch property keys of current edge
            ekeys=e.getPropertyKeys()

            //iterate through edge property keys
            for(String ekey:ekeys)
                eprop=e.getProperty(ekey) //get value of current property key
                goodprop=!(eprop == "" || eprop == null)
                mylog.info("*****READ*****edge key/value: "+ekey+"="eprop)

                /*determine placement of current key/value on one or neither of the 
               terminal vertices based on key prefix arges and property value,
               remove prefix from re-assigned key/value
               */

               if(ekey.startsWith(args[0]) && goodprop) {
                   vkey=ekey.split(args[0])[1]
                   if(!from.hasProperty(vkey)) from.setProperty(vkey, eprop)
                   else {
                       vprop=from.getProperty(vkey)
                       if(!vprop.equal(eprop) from.setProperty(vkey, vprop+";"+eprop)
                   }
                   mylog.info("*****READ*****from vertex key/value:  "+vkey+"="+from.getProperty(vkey)
               }
               else if(ekey.startsWith(args[1]) && goodprop) {
                   vkey=ekey.split(args[1])[1]
                   if(!to.hasProperty(vkey)) to.setProperty(vkey, eprop)
                   else {
                       vprop=to.getProperty(vkey)
                       if(!vprop.equal(eprop) to.setProperty(vkey, vprop+";"+eprop)
                   }
                   mylog.info("*****READ*****tovertex key/value:  "+vkey+"="+to.getProperty(vkey)
               }

               //if current edge property key is re-assigned, remove it from the edge
               if(ekey.startsWith(args[0]) || ekey.startsWith(args[1])) {
                   e.removeProperty(ekey)
                   if(e.hasProperty(ekey) println(ekey+" NOT remvoded from edge")
                   else println(ekey+ "removed from edge")
                }
                e.removeProperty("_namespace") // marks edge as processed per outer loop guard
            }
        }
    }
    g.commit()
}

def cleanup(args) {
    g.shutdown()
}
```

Comment: Short comment that's not related to your actual question: I would be surprised to see a difference between ```.in().count()``` and ```.inE().count()```. It should be enough to only use the latter.

Comment: you are correct given a simple graph (i.e., no reflexive or parallel edges).  But for a multi-graph (i.e., parallel edges), there can be a difference for particular vertices.  Specifically, for a given vertex: (# incident edges) - (# adjacent vertices) = (# parallel edges from /to one or more adjacent vertices).  Thus outE().count() - out().count() is (# parallel edges out), likewise for counts on inE() and in()

Comment: slight but crucial qualifier:  recently discovered that given parallel edges between a vertex pair, .in /.out return the same vertex as many times as there are edges!  So as written, Daniel is correct.  To achieve desired effect of counting distinct neighbors, I modified the code as [pipe].in().dedup.count()

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
if (e.hasProperty("_namespace")) {
```

`hasProperty` doesn't seem to be in the Blueprints API or the Titan API.  Since that is the case, I'm not sure how this code worked in your smaller test db, as it will always resolve to `false` and you will never see the inside of that `if` statement:

```
gremlin> x = TinkerGraphFactory.createTinkerGraph()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
gremlin> v = x.V('name','marko').next()                     
==>v[1]
gremlin> if (v.hasProperty('name')) { true } else { false } 
==>false
```

I suppose you really want to try this:

```
gremlin> if (v.getProperty('name')) { true } else { false }
==>true
gremlin> if (v.getProperty('xxx')) { true } else { false } 
==>false
```

Comment: Thanks for the help - will give this a shot & report back.  When I researched the method I didn't find it in Blueprints or Titan repositories, either.  However, I found it referenced in apparently relevant contexts: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19645913/create-complex-gremlin-java-query); [link] (http://api.neo4j.org/1.4/org/neo4j/graphdb/PropertyContainer.html). Did find an enlightening discussion here: [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6705029/groovy-hasproperty-respondsto)

Comment: this did the trick, implemented in the script map as follows:       if(!e.getProperty("_namespace)==null)